# Creating n nested loops in C++

Tags: python, c++, nested, nested-loops

I have been working on a program to calculate tetrations. To make it work with anything but 2, I need to have the amount of nested loops to change depending on the number entered. I have tried looking into it, but I can't quite understand other answers from questions on other posts (I am relatively new to C++).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    const float orgx = x;
    for (float y = 1;y <= orgx; y++) {
        x *= x;
    }
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's not impossible, but almost surely not what you should be doing. If you describe your actual problem, you are likely going to get better answers than when you describe the solution, which you came up with and don't know how to implement.

Comment: The usual approach is "increment with carry". You start with an array of `n` loop counters, all initialized to zero. Run the body of the loop. Increment `counter[0]`. Run the body. ... At some point, `counter[0]` will reach its upper bound - then reset it to zero and increment `counter[1]`. Repeat until `counter[n-1]` finally reaches the upper bound. This produces the same sequence of counters as `n` nested loops would.

Comment: What’s wrong with pow(x,pow(2,x))? That’s what your code will produce.

Comment: I’m guessing at what you want to do (from “tetrations”), but maybe you should consider recursion? But XY problem probably sums it up.

Comment: Look how Ackermann functions work. They can give you an arbitrary loop nesting (nesting (nesting …)) using recursion. Tetration is just one of an infinite series of Ackermann’s functions. Making it even remotely “efficient” may be quite tough. The super-easy Ackermann’s functions’ definition found on Wikipedia is beautiful from a computability standpoint, but doesn’t care about complexity too much.